# how to setup web service server with MySql for java developer

Tags: java, mysql, web-services

Hello Folks I am new to webservice I googled a lot I couldn't come to conclusion so I am seeking help here.

I am developing simple Android app for education purpose I know Java programming.

Please any one give me the steps to adopt in development to consume API signature from the webservice backend. If possible Local setup steps. I am using FrontEnd: Android widgets with http. I need backend setup  information JAVA restful + MySql + Application server ?

Advance thanks

Answer (score 0):

I personally run a server from home on a Raspberry Pi for my pet projects. It uses a LAMP setup, which stands for Linux+Apache+MySQL+PHP. Linux is the OS it runs on, Apache is the main webserver, and PHP is for dynamic webpage creation. I would recommend using something similar; packages like [WAMP](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/WampServer_HowTo.html) (replacing Linux with Windows) bundle all four of these services together for easy installation and setup. I believe there are also a number of free MySQL server hosts which you could use, if you don't want to deal with port-fowarding/handling traffic.